# Microsoft Bot Framework using variables in Prompts.choice

Tags: json, node.js, botframework

My current code for asking a yes/no question is

```
 builder.Prompts.choice(session, q15, "Yes|No", { listStyle: builder.ListStyle.button });
```

I want to store the strings "Yes" and "No" in a JSON file and access them by their variable names, instead of hardcoding it. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the definition of `choice()`:

> `choice(session: Session, prompt: TextOrMessageType, choices: string|Object|string[]|IChoice[], options?: IPromptChoiceOptions): void;`

You can pass a string array as the choices. So please consider the following code snippet:

```
//assume you have read the json string from a file and use it as following
const json_string = `{
    "VARIABLE_YES":"Yes",
    "VARIABLE_NO":"No"
}`;

const json_obj = JSON.parse(json_string);
builder.Prompts.choice(session, 'Make a choice', [json_obj.VARIABLE_YES, json_obj.VARIABLE_NO], {
    listStyle: builder.ListStyle.button
});
```